# Java report generation

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using `docx4j` for report generation in my java program. I can add text to the report but i cannot add images to the report.

I'm trying to add an image for the report using the following code

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

InputStream frontImageInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileNameAndPath));

byte[] binaryDataFrontImage = IOUtils.toByteArray(frontImageInputStream);

BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordprocessingMLPackage, binaryDataFrontImage);

wordprocessingMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("myfile.docx"));
```

Can anyone share any idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the image part, but you haven't added anything on the document surface to actually display it.

For a complete example, please see [ImageAdd.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ImageAdd.java)